# Web Share API navigator.share problem when canceling share dialog IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, vue.js

When using MOBILE SHARE (navigator.share), cancelling the Share flow causes an unexpected error to appear.
The message can be acknowledged and user is allowed to proceed but this error response is unexpected.

STEPS TO REPLICATE

1.Tap the SHARE icon to initiate the share dialog then:

2.a on iOS, find and tap the close <kbd>X</kbd> control in the upper righthand corner of the dialog to dismiss

2.b on Android, swipe the share overlay down (or whatever way to close/exit this dialog?)

3.The error "AbortError: About due to cancellation of share" appears when:

on iOS, immediately on cancellation

on Android, when attempting to re-engage the Share control.

The error message:

> [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) says: AbordError: Share canceled

I'm using this Vue plugin https://github.com/GabrielBibiano/vue-navigator-share

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue with Vue.js or any plugin, but something that `navigator.share` function does.

It is throwing this on canceling/dismissing share action.
Check this example on phone which supports `navigator.share`.

(NOTE: open this page as desktop site since phones can not run examples)

You can also see this (LOC: 303): https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/34eacf936ac3255925c5045c4385dc9b5f19fa78/chrome/android/javatests/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/webshare/WebShareTest.java

```js
const share = async () => {
  try {
    await navigator.share({ url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ' });
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.toString().includes('AbortError')) {
      alert('Hello world aborted :(');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="share()">share (only for phones)</button>
```

Comment: Share API also works for MacOS!